# React.js useRef is used to access the swiper.js instances like start() and stop(), only work on first render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, swiper.js

React.js useRef is used to access the swiper instances like start() and stop(), it will work on first render after that swiper instance is not available, I tried to create new Swiper using useEffect but it show error that ".Swiper is not constructor".

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Autoplay, Pagination } from "swiper";
import { Wrapper } from "./card.style";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import { IMG_URL } from "../../utils/Constants";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useMainContext } from "../../context/context";

const Card = ({ product }) => {
  const { setShowModal } = useMainContext();
  const cardElem = useRef("");
  const { swiper } = cardElem.current;
  console.log(cardElem.current.swiper);

  const cardslideStop = () => {
    swiper.autoplay.stop();
    console.log("stop")
  };
  const cardslideStart = () => {
    swiper.autoplay.start();
    console.log("start")
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollTop);
  }, []);

  // console.log(product?.images)

  return (
    <Link to={`/productdetail/${product?._id}`}>
      <Wrapper>
        <div
          className="card"
        >
          <div className="card-img">
            
              <Swiper
                pagination={true}
                modules={[Autoplay, Pagination]}
                slidesPerView={1}
                ref={cardElem}
                className="mySwiper"
              >
                {product?.images.map((curElem, index) => {
                  return (
                    <SwiperSlide
                      key={index}
                      onMouseEnter={cardslideStart}
                      onMouseLeave={cardslideStop}
                      style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        alignItems: "center"
                      }}
                    >
                      <img src={IMG_URL + curElem} alt="" />
                    </SwiperSlide>
                  );
                })}
              </Swiper>
            
          </div>
          <div className="card-title">
            <h3>{product?.product_name || "68 GSM Xerox A4 Size Paper"}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="card-price">
            <h3>{"₹ " + product?.product_price || "₹ 220/ Ream"}</h3>
          </div>
          {/* <div className="card-rating">
            <h3>{`⭐ ${product?.product_avg_rate} Ratings `}</h3>
          </div> */}
          <div className="card-button">
            <button onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>Enquiry Now</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Wrapper>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

This component is used to start slide images in this card after hovering on it. And when mouse leaves the card then slide stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the Swiper instance via a ref doesn't appear in the docs. You can use `onSwipe` [property](https://swiperjs.com/react#swiper-props) to get the current Swiper instance, and store it in a state:

To get and store the instance:

```
const [swiper, setSwiper] = useState(null);

<Swiper
  onSwiper={setSwiper}
  pagination={true}
  modules={[Autoplay, Pagination]}
  slidesPerView={1}
  className="mySwiper"
>
```

Using the instance:

```
const cardslideStop = () => {
  swiper?.autoplay?.stop();
  console.log("stop")
};

const cardslideStart = () => {
  swiper?.autoplay?.start();
  console.log("start")
};
```